# Passing multiple arguments to Rack middleware in Rails application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, ruby-on-rails-5, rack-middleware

I am creating a Rack Middleware which I want to use in my Rails App. Basically, I need to log requests matching particular urls to my Database. In order to do this I need to pass database configuration to my Middleware so it can establish connection with DB. I am trying to do:-

```
db_yml = Rails.root.join('config/database.yml')
db_config = YAML.load(db_yml.read)[Rails.env]
```

But this is giving an error

> config/application.rb:40:in `<class:Application>': undefined method`read' for # (NoMethodError)

If I add byebug and run the same in the byebug console it works fine. I am not able to find out why. I want to do following things:-

1. I need to read & modify the database configuration before passing it to my middleware as argument.
2. I want to read the domain of the request url. We are using [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem and Our schema name will be the domain name.

I followed multiple articles [here](http://deliv.github.io/2014/01/31/rack-middleware-to-log-api-requests-in-mongodb/) & [here](http://ieftimov.com/writing-rails-middleware).
I am a newbie to Rails and don't know good resources so please help. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
db_yml = Rails.root.join('config/database.yml')
db_config = YAML.load(File.open(db_yml))[Rails.env]
```

`Rails.root.join('config/database.yml')` return the file path which is a string.

Comment: But why does my snippet work in byebug console? And how can I access the request URL in application.rb?